# Passing a dynamic where clause through Web API

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am currently in the process of creating a.NET Core Web API that is going to interact with an Angular front end. There is a requirement for the web API to be able to return data based on a dynamically built where statement. For example, I have an object with the following model

```
{
    "accountCode": "ABC123",
    "addressLine1": "AddressLine1",
    "addressLine2": "AddressLine2",
    "addressLine3": "AddressLine3",
    "addressLine4": null,
    "addressLine5": null,
    "businessUnitName": "",
    "companyRegistrationNumber": null,
    "name": "My supplier",
    "postcode": "BA112RP",
    "supplierId": 3,
    "vatRegistrationNumber": null
}
```

Now rather than having my controller method setup with 12 different parameters and needing to add an extra parameter whenever I add a new property is there a way I can have a dynamic parameter (KeyValuePair type arrangement)?

Comment: While re-reading your question, I realised that I misread your question.

Could you please clarify your request? You are trying to send a KeyValuePair from you WebAPI-Controller to your Angular Front-End? I see nothing hindering you on that. A Dictionary<string,string> or a JObject (Newtonsoft.JSON) should do the trick

Comment: I'm looking to pass a KeyValuePair from my front end to my WebApi. Your answer to the original question solved it, just hadn't got chance to mark it as correct yet. Thanks a lot Severin

Comment: Then i'm happy I could help :) Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your asp.net-core web api is able to implicitly convert input into any given Object, for example:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
    public IActionResult PostObject([FromBody] MyObject obj)
    {
        // Your Code goes here
    }
}
```

By default this expects a JSON format but you can use others like FormData as well.

Also it mustn't be an object with the defined properties. You can use a simple KeyValuePair as well. Have a look at [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) where you can find additional advice on how to best solve your Problem.